Flutter showDialog not dismissing after navigator.pop
In the below code a popUp dialog is shown. I want the _startLongRunningLoop to be called once popup dialog is closed. Right now, the popup dialog remains open until _startLongRunningLoop  is complete. How can I do it?
Simplified dummy example
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Dialog Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  void _showFormDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Form Dialog'),
          content: FormDialog(),
        );
      },
    );
    _startLongRunningLoop();
  }

  void _startLongRunningLoop() {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 1000000) {
      print('Long running loop: $count');
      count++;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Dialog Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _showFormDialog(context);
          },
          child: Text('Open Form Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormDialogState createState() => _FormDialogState();
}

class _FormDialogState extends State<FormDialog> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _submitForm() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your name';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _submitForm,
            child: Text('Submit'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

In this example, even though Navigator.pop() is called, the dialog still remains on screen until _startLongRunningLoop is completed.

As you can see, the button is pressed and the popup dismisses once the _startLongRunningLoop is complete
Things I have tried
Sol1
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Dialog Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  void _showFormDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    var t = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Form Dialog'),
          content: FormDialog(),
        );
      },
    );
    if (t == "true") {
      _startLongRunningLoop();
    }
  }

  void _startLongRunningLoop() {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 1000000) {
      print('Long running loop: $count');
      count++;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Dialog Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _showFormDialog(context);
          },
          child: Text('Open Form Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormDialogState createState() => _FormDialogState();
}

class _FormDialogState extends State<FormDialog> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _submitForm() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop("true");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your name';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _submitForm,
            child: Text('Submit'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Hey I am really confused on the dialog you used CustomForm but you showed the code for TradingForm and according to the code of the TradingForm what you want should work correctly I mean the submit will be called after the dialog is closed.
And a suggestion please add proper type to your functions(so instead of Function use void Function() or whatever the function will return)

@MDIsmailAlamKhan Thankyou for taking a look. When the buy button is clicked,  Navigator.of(context).pop("true"); is called. I expect the AlertDialog and showDialog to dismiss after that and main screen should be visible. But that is not happening. If you consider my Sol2, "new beg" is getting printed but the dialog is still open. SubmitSoltuion is an empty while loop to mimic long running process. I expect. the popup to close once "popped out" is printed in TradingForm.
CustomForm == TradingForm (my bad)

@MDIsmailAlamKhan I have added a simpler example which you can run on dartpad or local.

"even though Navigator.pop() is called, the dialog still remains on screen until _startLongRunningLoop is completed." - this is because the new frame has to be drawn - with your tight loop you are preventing this

Hello you can try something like this :
var valueReturned = await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text("Title :"),
            content: CustomForm(
                lastClosePrice: latestPrice.close,
                onBuy: (double _entryPrice, int _qty, double _targetPrice) {
                    print("Buy button pressed");
                    await setPuzzleSubmissionDTO(PuzzleSubmissionDTO(
                        entryPrice: _entryPrice,
                        targetPrice: _targetPrice,
                        qty: _qty,
                    ));
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(valueYouWantToReturned);
                },
            );
        );
    }
);
if(valueReturned){
    //Treatment
}

Edit (you can run your treatment in an isolate thread) :
Future<String> _startLongRunningLoop(String? value) async {
    final String res = await Isolate.run<String>(() {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 100000) {
            if (kDebugMode) {
                print('Long running loop: $count');
            }
            count++;
        }
        return "Done";
    });
    return res;
}


tried that too... the valueReturned is giving the appropriate value but the popup is still present

I ma using this one and it works perfectly, check if there is anything you missed.

Cam you try with the dummy example I have posted?
void _showFormDialog(BuildContext context) async {
var t = await showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
return AlertDialog(
title: Text('Form Dialog'),
content: FormDialog(),
);
},
);
if (t == "true") {
_startLongRunningLoop();
}
}

You can check the edited code

I would say that Navigator depends on the context, and when we call Navigator.of(context).pop(); it identifies the screen to close by its context.
Solution that I will suggest you is that to close the dialogue you need the context from the builder so you should create a function in the contructor of formfield and should call that function when you have to close the popup and then in the function in show dialogue just pass navigator.of(context).pop
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Form Dialog'),
          content: FormDialog(pop: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()
          ),
        );
      },
    )

Like this
Hope this helps

Run After Dialog Closes
In your question you ask:

I want the _startLongRunningLoop to be called once popup dialog is closed.

Use .then() on showDialog to run something once popup dialog is closed.
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Basic dialog title'),
          content: const Text(
            'Some Dialog',
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Close'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    ).then((_) { /// THIS RUNS AFTER DIALOG CLOSES
      print("This runs after dialog closes.");
    });

Notes:

the underscore _ in then((_)) is capturing the return value from the closed dialog.  If you're not caring about the return value from the dialog, it's common to use _ to note we're not using it / don't care about its value.
if you want to add a delay before running something, you can use async / await like so:

    ).then((_) async {
      print("This runs after dialog closes.");
      print('Waiting for 3 sec...');
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
      print('Done.');
    });


this won't flood your app's event loop like counting to a million which would cause janky/weird behavior.  Dart is single threaded and has only one event loop and a microtask queue/loop, so things like loops can effectively block the event loop, preventing other code from executing.  You can read more about that here.


Just await the showDialog and the next function will call once the dialog is closed

Thankyou for your response. If you mean something like I have mentioned in Sol1, it is not working

That's really weird what's that subnussionDTO doing?

I have edited the answer to a simplied example which can be replicated. In general, there's nothing special about the _startLongRunningLoop. Just a long running process.

Oh ok give me a sec to run the example, sorry I was referring to the old example

@Ojasvsingh weird I ran the example and it works as expected, the _startLongRunningLoop gets called after the dialog is popped

Umm... does the popup go away before the loop is terminated? For me the popup stays on the screen until the loop is terminated.

That is maybe because the loop is too long so the app gets stuck use a smaller value
